# How can I focus on a whole row of a JTable?

Tags: java, swing, focus, jtable, row

I have a `JTable` that is showing some records in a Java Swing application. The user only works with whole rows, not with individual cells. Is there any way I can focus on a whole row of a `JTable`? The default is to focus only the cell that the user has clicked on. I use a different color for the focus, so it doesn't look good if only a cell is focused instead of the whole row.

**UPDATE:** This is my current code of my custom `TableCellRenderer`, the issue is that when a row has focus and is painted with the "focus" color, and then the `JTable` loses focus, only the **cell** that had focus is repainted with the "selected" color but all cells in the selected row should be repainted with the "selected" color.

```
@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
        Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
        int row, int column) {

    // Has any cell in this row focus?
    if(table.getSelectedRow() == row && table.hasFocus()) {
        hasFocus = true;
    }

    if (hasFocus) {
        this.setBackground(CustomColors.focusedColor);
    } else if (isSelected) {
        this.setBackground(CustomColors.selectedColor);
    } else {

        // alternate the color of every second row
        if(row % 2 == 0) {
            this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        } else {
            this.setBackground(CustomColors.grayBg);
        }
    }

    setValue(value);

    return this;

}
```

Comment: Would it be sufficient to use custom cellrenderer to display all cells in the row as they would have focus?

Comment: @Howard: Yes, that would be sufficient, if you have a suggestion.

Comment: See also [Table Row Rendering](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<del>Sounds like you're looking for [the `setRowSelectionAllowed()` method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setRowSelectionAllowed%28boolean%29).</del>

Since you said just changing the color would be sufficient, you might want to look at the [custom cell renderer section](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer) of the Swing Tutorial. You'd just have to set the logic to check on whether a given cell was in a selected row, and paint the background color accordingly.

Comment: That's a good suggestion, but I have an issue. When the `JTable` is losing focus, only the focused cell is repainted (with the "selected" color) and the other cells on the row still has the "focused" color, since they aren't repainted. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Jonas, have the renderer explicitly set the "normal" background color on all cells that aren't in selected rows, instead of just ignoring them.

Comment: I have solved it. I added a `FocusListener` for the `JTable` and call `repaint()` in `focusLost()`.

Answer (score 1):

A first idea would be something like

```
JTable jTable = new JTable() {
    public TableCellRenderer getCellRenderer(int row, int column) {
        final TableCellRenderer superRenderer = super.getCellRenderer(row, column);
        return new TableCellRenderer() {

            @Override
            public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object object, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
                // determine focus on row attribute only
                hasFocus = hasFocus() && isEnabled() && getSelectionModel().getLeadSelectionIndex() == row;
                return superRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, object, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
            }
        };
    }
};
```

where I use my own logic to determine the focus based on the row attribute only. It uses the underlying cell renderers but looks strange if focus border is used.

Comment: Thanks, but I think this has the same issue as my code that I posted in my updated question. When the `JTable` loses focus, only the cell that had focus is repainted. So the other cells on the row will still have the "focus" color.